# Crashlytics Swift wrong error "path" on Firebase dashboard

Tags: swift, error-handling, crashlytics, rx-swift

I created an extension of `Observable`, `Single` and `Completable` to report a **non-fatal** issues to Crashlytics when an error occurs in the `do(onError:)` RxSwift method.

It works like that : `myObservable.handleError()`. This method is functional, but the report in Firebase dashboard doesn't show the real source of the error.

My `handleError` method call the log method of the Logger class, which is implemented this way :

```
class Logger {

    static let shared = Logger()

    public func log(_ error: Error) {
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
    }

}
```

On the Firebase dashboard, the file that appears is the Logger.swift, not the file & the line where error occurs.

Is there a way to have the right file in the dashboard ?